# Android - Two AsyncTask running parallelly - Exception

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I develop a mobile app where clicking on button in Activity A triggers Activity B as well an async task. In Activity B, there is a async task which gets trigerred in the oncreate method. So, there will be 2 async task which will be running parallelly. both the async task interact with the server. (POST and GET method respectively)

All is good when the server is up and running. When I make the server deliberately down and click on the button in Activity A, I am not sure where the control is going. I expect a connectiontimeout exception and I am getting it. But sometimes the async task in Activity B's exception occurs  first and sometimes the async task in Activity A's exception occurs first.

In the catch block in both the async method, there is an intent which starts anotheractivity (No server Connection activity)

Once after the exception ( in both of the async methods) has occured I am not seeing any logs in the Logcat. I believe  the app comes to a standstill. I wish to gracefully inform the other async task which ever is running to stop.

Could anyone please help me in accomplishing this task. Is there any good design approach to handle this? Let me know and thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: I am not sure whether I have stated my question correctly. What I mean to say here is by reading the status of one asynctask in activity A the other asynctask in Activity B should stop its execution if asynctask in activity A encounters a connection timeout exception.  Do I need to reference the instance of the async task of Activity A in Activity B. If yes, can anyone help me with a code sample. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing your own timeout detection and handling.
Use handler and provide timeout period when firing the ASyncTask

```
private void readFromServer(String url, int timeout) {
    // read from server
    final ServerHit serverHit = new ServerHit(this);//ServerHit is my asyncTask
    serverHit.execute(url);
    // set a timeout
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (serverHit.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
            {
                serverHit.cancel(true);
            }
        }
    }, timeout);
   }
```

However if you call only one instance of each AsyncTask consider declare it as a static or let it follow the Singleton Pattern. And upon cancelling one task just cancel the other one.

**EDIT**

You can define those asyncatasks as static and can cancel them on timeout

Comment: Thanks. I will implement this and let you know the outcome

Answer (score 0):

You should read the first "Related" post on the right "Is AsyncTask really conceptually flawed or am I just missing something?".

Your attempt to do what you are doing, shows little understanding of how the Android OS manages Activities and their AsyncTasks.  Trying to start one from Activity A and then start Activity B before it finishes is doomed to fail.